# open new html in same tab caused problems

Tags: javascript, html

Im tyring to open new html in the same tab so I added `"_self"`, but since I use it the function not respond so well, it cant load all the content and basically it cause my program no to work as it worked without `"_self"`.

p.s. - I using window.opener.var so it might be the reason.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

```
window.open('category.html',"_self");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
  window.location.href = "category.html";
```

You are using a `window.open ()` method that open your page in a new tab.
With `window.location.href` you change the url in the same tab.

Comment: I can use in the new page that I loaded with the method window.opener?

Comment: I see that now the var the I defined as window.var are not familiar to the new page..